Caculate nth derivative of $(\arctan x)^2$ at $x=0$
Let $f(x)=(\arctan x)^2$, we can know that $f'(x)=2\arctan x \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.
$(f'(x))^2\cdot (1+x^2)^2=4f(x)$, caculate derivative both side and we get $f'(x)x(1+x^2)+f''(x)(1+x^2)^2\cdot \frac{1}{2}=1$.
Use Leibniz formula we can get a recurrence relation between $f^{(n-1)}(0)$,$f^{(n+1)}(0)$,$f^{(n+1)}(0)$.(if I didn't make mistakes)
But the relation is too complex and hard to find a general formula. Are there any simple solutions?

You could use the Maclaurin series of $\arctan x$ (which is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1 + x^2}$, which can be derived from the geometric series). Naturally, you'll have to square said power series, which will make each term a finite sum (the number of terms increasing with $n$), but at least you'll be able to express the $n$ derivative in terms of this finite sum.

Do you need the Taylor series of $(\arctan{x})^2$? In that case you can square the Taylor series of $\arctan{x}$ to find the coefficients.

Thanks. I'll try it. But since $(\arcsin x)^2$ can be solved in the way I wrote, I wonder if $\arctan$ can be solved in the same way.

Thanks @metamorphy. That's the question.
